# After installing BigBlueButton 2.3-dev, I am unable to connect via SSH. Why?

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-18.04, bigbluebutton

I have a VPN server (on A2Hosting) with Ubuntu 18.04 installed. The server meets the minimum configuration required for BBB. I was able to connect to this server via ssh and installed BBB 2.3-dev. It installed successfully and I can access the main page in my browser. But, after install SSH is not working. When I try to connect, it says connection timeout.

```
ssh: connect to host 1xx.xxx.xxx.xx7 port xxx2: Connection timed out
```

I have tried resetting the server, reinstall operating system and bbb several times, but whenever bbb install without error, SSH stops working. I am facing this for last couple of days. Please suggest what can be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging, I found that the port was blocked by firewall. My hosting provider was using non-standard ssh port 7822. Unblockimg the port solved the issue.

```
ufw allow 7822
```